# Get currently applied Angular Material theme from component

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, angular-material2

I have defined 3 themes in my `_variables.scss` that is imported in my `styles.scss` file :

1. Blue theme
2. Green theme
3. Red theme

I apply those themes on components using classes defined at root stylesheet, such as :

```
.blue-theme {
  @include mat-button-theme($my-blue-theme);
  @include mat-form-field-theme($my-blue-theme);
  @include mat-input-theme($my-blue-theme);
  ...
}
.green-theme { ... }
.red-theme { ... }
```

Let say I have the following structure :

```
- Component A
  - Component AA
  - Component AB
- Component B
```

I dynamically switch theme on `component A` by applying corresponding class. Works well.

But when binding theme in `component A`, **I would like AA and AB to change as well**, like a standard material component would, without any service or ubiquitous theme variable strategy.

For the moment, the only solution I came up with is to create one component per theme, that is absolutely not maintainable.

The best solution would be to use `mat-color()` or `mat-get()` functions, but as far as I understood they need to be **called with a well known theme**, not the theme that is currently used.

Any thought about this ?

Comment: That sounds like it _should_ work, but you haven't shared any component code or the code that does the dynamic class assignment, so it's hard to be certain. Angular Material themes and functions etc. live in the world of SASS. Through compilation, at run time they take the form of pure CSS. So anything you need to do dynamically needs to be done via either CSS (or Javascript).

Comment: Component A dynamic class assignment works well, but since AA and AB are custom components too (not material), I am wondering how am I supposed to code those two subcomponents in order to get the expected behaviour. I don't think "it should work" since I have done nothing yet for those components :). I just feel that functions like `mat-color` or `mat-get` could make the work, problem is that they take a specific palette as parameter.

Comment: The `.blue-theme ...` section you showed is the usual way to tackle this. If you have theming mixins for your own components, you need to add those mixin calls to the various `@include mat-???-theme()` calls in each base theme class.

Comment: By doing that, it will adapt material children components, that's ok, but I want to be able to use these dynamically changed colors in AA and AB without knowing the theme that is currently applied. (I want, for example, a variable `$background-color-theme` in AB that binds automatically according to the A component primary theme color). Sorry if I was unclear

Comment: SASS variables live in SASS - at run time they are merely values in CSS. There is no CSS "binding" - there can only be CSS rules. e.g. `.blue-theme AA { background-color: blue; }` which can be done using standard theming https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components e.g. `.blue-theme { @include my-aa-component-theme($my-blue-theme); ... } .red-theme { @include my-aa-component-theme($my-red-theme); ... }`.